# How to select alternate rows from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

Having two tables, I want to display the result from alternate rows from both tables, just like `UNION ALL`.

Can you help me to find out the solution in a MS SQL Server query?

Records of `Table1`:

```
id - value
-------------
 1 - abc
 4 - dce
 9  - fgh
 16 - ijk 
 25 - lmn
```

Records of `Table2`:

```
id - value
-------------
 5 - opq
 10 - rst
 15 - uvw
 20 - xyz 
 25 - zab
```

The result I want:

```
Id - value 
-----------
 1 - abc
 5 - opq
 15 - uvw
 9  - fgh
 15 - uvw
 20 - xyz 
 16 - ijk 
 25 - lmn 
 25 - zab 

----------------
```

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. If you want results to appear in a particular order you have to tell us (and SQL Server) what the rules are for what order the rows should be sorted into. You're unlikely to get an answer at the moment since we have no idea what the tables even look like, let alone what the correct rule is.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will do it for you, but you have to change the query and add your table names and your column names in the `ORDER BY` statement of the `OVER` clause.

Also, take note that both of your tables must have the same number of columns, and the same datatypes in order for them to work in an `UNION`.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column),
    1 AS 'rowOrder',
    *
FROM TABLE1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column),
    2 AS 'rowOrder',
    *
FROM TABLE2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: using just ROWNUM? (if tables are actually populated in the same way...)

Comment: @FrancescoGabbrielli typically you would expect OP to post a sample dataset which is similar to his real one. So, the problem that I am solving is quite specific and there is no room for interpretation of the scenario.